# append() happens before hide()

Tags: jquery

I'd like to hide all children then append otherChild. The problem is sometimes append() happens first then hide() happens (Chrome, Firefox).

What I expect:

```
Parent
Other child
```

But sometimes it prints:

```
Parent
Child
```

Actually if I run this code in IE9, it always print:

```
Parent
Child
```

Full code

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Hide children.
    $(".parent").children().hide();

    // Append more child.
    $(".parent").append("<div class=\"otherChild\">Other child</div>");
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="parent">
        Parent
        <div class="child">
            Child
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works perfect on IE9,10 and Chrome

Comment: Should I provide a screenshot? Think before downvote please!

Comment: I did not downvote. I just said its working. Try using callback to `hide()`.

Comment: Yes you're right, I've been through such situations. We cannot predict OPs browser behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9fp6/1/)**

Use a callback with `hide()` - **[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)**

`.hide('duration',callback)`  :

- First argument takes the duration of the event. If you want a quick hide event use `0` in this field.
- Second the callback, which executes after the hide event is complete.

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".parent").children().hide(0, function() {
        $(".parent").append('<div class="otherChild">Other child</div>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Execuse me, is there the same effect if I do hide().append()?

Answer (score 3):

Then trigger the function on a `complete`:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Hide children.
    $(".parent").children().hide(2000, function() {
      // Append more child.
      $(".parent").append("<div class=\"otherChild\">Other child</div>");
    });
});
</script>
```